# Why can't I use anonymous arrays as any other anonymous class?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing on my IDE the following inside the main method

```
public static void main(String... args){
    new String(); // no compilation fail
    new Object(); // no compilation fail
    new int[]{1,2,3,4}; // compilation fails
}
```

why arrays can't be anonymous as other objects?

I can see I can use them anonymously when we talk about passing them as method params, however I was expecting them to behave as any other object even for this case.

Comment: What are you trying to achieved, what actual code are you trying to compile, and what error message are you getting?

Comment: absolutely nothing to achieve, this is just simply curiosity.

Comment: What do you mean by "anonymous"? Is it that it is not assigned to any variable?

Comment: an array which is not assigned to a variable, this is a known subject: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/anonymous-array-java/

Comment: `new int[]{1,2,3,4}`, as `{1,2,3,4}` is an array literal. It's like writing `"foo";`, it doesn't compile by language design if you don't assign that value to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
public static void main(String... args){
   new String(); // no compilation fail
   new Object(); // no compilation fail
   int[] ia = new int[]{1,2,3,4}; // compilation fails
```

}

Indeed, if you have no reference to the newly created array, it is not accessible and so its creation was in vain. On the other hand, object creation without saving the reference may have sense - to check if it throws an exception or not.

Answer (score 5):

A class constructor can contain any arbitrary instructions, therefore there will be circumstances where just calling the constructor of a class is doing everything you want to do.

Creating a new array doesn't *do* anything, it cannot possibly execute instructions that would be defined somewhere. It is fundamentally incapable to serve a purpose if you're not going to *use* the array thus created.

Comment: Hence `new X()` is a **statement**, and `new X[]` is _not_ so in the java language specification. `X()` could do something.

Comment: Sorry but when you guys say "it cannot possibly execute instructions that would be defined somewhere" I can say that I can do new int[]{1,2}.toString() ... so potentially it can do something...

Comment: @OEH Well that's a method call, not just creating the array. Doing that makes it a statement and compiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public  static void somemethod(int a []){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new String(); // no compilation fail
            new Object(); // no compilation fail
            somemethod(new int[]{1,2,3,4}); }  // compilation will not fails now
```

> You need `X(array here)` , do this and you are good to go.
>
> `new array[]` is not a statement.

Comment: in my question i mentioned "I can see I can use them anonymously when we talk about passing them as method params"

Comment: new `array[]` is not a statement , Lol BTW you have too much attitude.

Comment: lol sorry about that I didn't want to sound rude, I was typing in hurry. Thanks for your effort